# Is it possible to change the Google Sites DOM from GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a Google Sites page with an Apps Script Gadget. The code for the app script is as follows:

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("changedom");
}
```

**changedom.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function changeDom() {
        console.log('Testing container DOM change...');
        var spanTitle = $('sites-page-title');
        if(spanTitle) {
          console.log($('sites-page-title').innerHTML);
          spanTitle.innerHTML = spanTitle.innerHTML + ' (change)';
          console.log(spanTitle.innerHTML);
        }
      }
      changeDom();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Where 'sites-page-title' is a DOM object out of my Google App Script Gadget, because it is the Google Sites page title.

And the console log when running in Chrome is:

```
...
Testing container DOM change...
undefined
undefined (change)
...
```

And the DOM object with id sites-page-title isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code cannot access anything outside the gadget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Corey. Is this due to restrictions in Google Sites? or is the Google Caja which impose the limitations? or something else?

Comment: Both? Caja/Apps Script disallows this, but it's running inside an iframe anyways so it wouldn't work even without Caja.